# Universal Static Libraires - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, static-libraries, ipa

I have built a static library & would like to distribute it.

I can create an `universal library` containing binaries of both `Simulator(i386 architecture)` & `Device(arm architecture)`.

However, will the universal library impact the size of the application it is being used, since it also has simulator binary in it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the actual lib byte size has nothing to do with the final app byte size - the linker will only include relevant (referenced) symbols out of the ones in the built architecture. For example, I have built a univ. lib 5mb in size, but only affects the final app size +260Kb